# Identical records in IIS logs

Tags: iis7, logging

While inspecting the web server logs, I came across several instances of separate records that look just the same. For example:

```
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2020-04-21 00:00:10 ABC.128.138.15 GET /MY/API/HERE departmentId=&prodLineId=&prodUnitId=&puGroupId=&FLId=null&startTime=2019-09-08T21:00:00.000Z&endTime=2019-09-09T21:00:00.000Z&status=null&itemType=&itemComponent=&howFound=&priority=&foundBy=&fixedBy=&flList= 80 - ABC.128.138.15 Apache-HttpClient/4.5.6+(Java/1.8.0_92) - 200 0 0 1453
2020-04-21 00:00:10 ABC.128.138.15 GET /MY/API/HERE departmentId=&prodLineId=&prodUnitId=&puGroupId=&FLId=null&startTime=2019-09-08T21:00:00.000Z&endTime=2019-09-09T21:00:00.000Z&status=null&itemType=&itemComponent=&howFound=&priority=&foundBy=&fixedBy=&flList= 80 - ABC.128.138.15 Apache-HttpClient/4.5.6+(Java/1.8.0_92) - 200 0 0 1453
```

Do those records correspond to two actual separate requests, or perhaps it was just one that for some reason got duplicated? This is not an isolated occurrence (there are hundreds more). Just for the record, these are all GET requests coming from the same source (an Apache Tomcat-based application that resides in the same web server and is invoking APIs in different application pools).

Comment: It's been a long time since I used IIS, but I don't ever recall seeing duplicated entries that weren't legit.  I suspect that the app is just using a webservice call of some kind.

Comment: I get duplicated entries in my Apache log files as well.  I haven't looked into how they get created, so I can't give you any details.